# Is there any relation between the principal eigenvalue of sub matrix and the original matrix?

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

I am wondering whether there is any relation between principal eigenvalue of sub matrix and the original matrix.

In fact I am facing a problem which is to select $n$ rows and $n$ columns from the original non-negative matrix to construct a new matrix. The principal eigenvalue of the small matrix selected need to be close to certain constant.

I have totally no idea how to start...

I guess figuring out the relation maybe a good starting point of this problem.

**UPDATE:**
I set up a conceptual optimization problem, hope this can help on the understanding of my problem.

$\min |\max (xAx')-\lambda^*|$

s.t. $\lVert x\rVert_2=1$

$x_i=[w_iv_i]$

$v_i>0$

$w_i=\{0,1\}$

$\sum_i w_i=n$

$A$ is the original matrix, $n$ is the number of rows/columns I used to construct the small matrix, $\lambda^*$ is the target constant of the principal eigenvalue of small matrix.

What I want to know is the $w$ vector

Comment: There is an interlacing theorem due to Cauchy.

Answer (score 4):

Likely, the best you're going to get will come from the Cauchy Interlace Theorem that @user32309 referred to.  You can see a proof of the result [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4145217) in the paper "Cauchy's Interlace Theorem for Eigenvalues of Hermitian Matrices" by Suk-Geun Hwang and it states

**Theorem 1 (Cauchy Interlace Theorem)**. Let $A$ be a Hermitian matrix of order $n$, and let $B$ be a principal submatrix of $A$ of order $n - 1$. If $\lambda_n\leq \lambda_{n-1}\leq \dots\leq \lambda_2\leq \lambda_1$, lists the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\mu_n\leq \mu_{n-1}\leq \dots\leq \mu_3\leq \mu_2$ the eigenvalues of $B$, then $\lambda_n\leq \mu_n\leq\lambda_{n-1}\leq\mu_{n-1}\leq \dots\leq \lambda_2\leq \mu_2\leq\lambda_1$.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering whether there is any relation between principal eigenvalue of sub matrix and the original matrix.

I put out a paper with Terry Tao and others [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795) (see Terry's blog post [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/08/13/eigenvectors-from-eigenvalues/)) which provides an answer to this question (we first found the result [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.02534) in the context of particle physics).

The result is as follows: Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_i(A)$. Let $M_j$ be the $n-1\times n-1$ submatrix that results from deleting the $j$th row and column which has $n-1$ eigenvalues $\lambda_i(M_j)$. Let the eigenvectors of $A$ be $v_i$ with elements $v_{i,j}$. Then,

$$|v_{i,j}|^2\prod_{k=1;k\neq i}^n(\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_k(A))=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(\lambda_i(A)-\lambda_k(M_j))$$

Terry provided a plethora of proofs for this which I won't repeat here.

Comment: this recent MO posting may be of interest in this connection: https://mathoverflow.net/q/346264/11260